# How can I access a variable dynamically in a script not attached to the gameobject itself in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have several gameobjects: each have an "Interactable" and "Data" class. I also have a "PauseGameController" class not attached to those gameobjects in which I want to use the data for each object dynamically if an event is triggered when the Key I is pressed AND the variable "isInteracting" from the "Interactable" class is true. In other words , the "PauseGameController" class does not know which gameobject data will be using until this 2 events happend for one specific object

My question is:

How can I retrieve the data dynamically that I typed on the inspector in the class "Data" for each gameobject from another script not attached to this gameobject?

I want to re-use the "data" and "interactable" class and be able to set different data to different gameobjects as I am creating them in the scene. And I don't want to use the Finds functions because the documentation says that it's slow.

Code:
**Interactables class**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Interactables : MonoBehaviour {

    public static bool interactable = false;
    public bool interactableown = false;


    public Material[] material;
    Renderer rend;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.enabled = true;
        rend.sharedMaterial = material[0];
    }



    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (interactableown)
        {
            rend.sharedMaterial = material[1];
        }else
        {
            rend.sharedMaterial = material[0];
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            interactable = true;
            interactableown = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            interactable = false;
            interactableown = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Pause Class**

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class Puase : MonoBehaviour {

        public static bool isPause = false;
        public  GameObject MenuUI;

        public Text txt;

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.I) && Interactables.interactable)
            {
                if (isPause)
                {
                    Resume();
                }
                else
                {
                    Pause();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Resume()
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;

            MenuUI.SetActive(false);
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
            isPause = false;
        }

        public void Pause()
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = true;

            MenuUI.SetActive(true);
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
            isPause = true;
        }
    }
```

**Data Class**

```
   using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class DataObj : MonoBehaviour {

    public string info = "";

    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

**Capture of the editor**
[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsQSl.png)

Comment: So you have the gameobject, and want the attached Data-component?

Comment: From another script not attached to this gameobject, yes. But, I have several gameobjects, so I want the data for each one, let's say if I'm close to the object named "cube" and press a key, the word "cube" will be shown but if I'm close to the object named "sphere" and press a key, then the word "sphere" will be shown

Comment: So, would this work? someGameObject.GetComponent<Data>()? That will return the Data-component of the gameobject

Comment: And how I know who is "someGameObject"? how I know that I'm close to a cube and not a sphere or a capsule? Should I put all of them in a list and then loop to see which one has the "isInteracting" flag set to true for that particular moment? But I want to avoid having to loop through many objects.

Comment: Perhaps you could present the code so its a bit clearer what you want to achive

Comment: On the information object (canvas) there is a Text object, I want the data to be shown in that Text object. The "pause" class it's attached to the "Information" canvas.

Comment: I found a way, creating a class show and make a public reference to the Text object on the canvas on it, and assigning the "show" class to every object that I want to show on that Text.